# Unison: Ignore directory by name in all paths by using command line

Tags: command-line, unison

I'm currently using unison for syncing local files with my cloud. Therefore I have set up a batch file which contains all options I need.

```
"K:\unison\unison 2.48.4 text.exe" -batch -repeat 1200 -fastcheck true -log=false D:\localsync Z:\cloudsync
```

In order to tell unison to skip all folders with the name ".tmp" regardless of their path I came up with this command:

```
 "K:\unison\unison 2.48.4 text.exe" -batch -repeat 1200 -fastcheck true -log=false -ignore=Name{*.*.tmp} D:\localsync Z:\cloudsync
```

The `*.*.tmp` construct is recommend since unison ignores all names beginning with a dot.

Unfortunately, unison throws an error here when I run the batch file:

> Uncaught exception Sys_error("C:\Users\name\.unison\*.tmp)

It then complains that the syntax for the directory name is wrong. Obviously, unison is reading the ignore statement and looking for a file with the name of the to be ignored folder in the .unison directory.

I couldn't come up with a solution to that. All information in the manual ([https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html)) sets ignore paths in the unison profile which I'm not using.

How's the way to get unison to ignore some directories when only using command line options?

Comment: Sorry for coming in late, but are you sure you don't need to enclose the argument to `-ignore` in quotes, to prevent the shell from expanding the wildcards (`*`) ? I'm not familiar with the shells in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong. Try

```
-ignore 'Name {*.*.tmp}'
```

From the [Unison manual](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore)

> Ignore patterns can also be specified on the command line, if you like (this is probably not very useful), using an option like -ignore 'Name temp.txt'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try this I get an syntax error from unison: Uncaught exception Sys_error("C:\\Users\\name\\.unison\\{*.*.tmp}': The syntax for file name, directory name or volume is wrong. Unison apparently tries to open a file named *.*.tmp.